# Can't display french accents Rstudio

Tags: r, encoding, diacritics

I import my database.csv file with `data <- read.csv("database.csv, sep = ";", header = TRUE, encoding = "utf-8")`
But when I display my data, all the accents are replace by \303\251.
I did `file -I database.csv` in my terminal to check the encoding and it's utf-8

Comment: I had the same question, but on my side `encoding = "utf-8"` solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Use parameter `fileEncoding` instead of `encoding`.

Comment: I tried but I got a warning message:  
  
Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  invalid input found on input connection '/Users/thomasvannier/Stage/SNCF/AFC/database.csv'
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on '/Users/thomasvannier/Stage/SNCF/AFC/database.csv'

Comment: Don't know about the first, but the second is clear: manually edit the file by adding a carriage return after the last line.